# Gatsby: Head is not defined

Tags: gatsby

Gatsby introduces Head API in version 4.19.0 (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-head/)

After updating Gatsby to version 4.19.0 and using the Head API in my code, I had the following error message : `Head is not defined`.

`src/pages/index.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react"
const Page = () => <div>Hello World</div>
export default Page
export function Head() {
  return (
    <title>Hello World</title>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-gatsby
```

Then, in the `.babelrc` file, add this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "Gatsby",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I use `.tsx`, I had to upgrade `gatsby-plugin-typescript` to version 4.19.0 too.

`npm i --save gatsby-plugin-typescript@^4.19.0`

Comment: If you're not setting any options you can remove the plugin as it's integrated into `gatsby` by default